# Regular expression in python finding dates

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expressions in python to finds dates like 09/2010 or 8/1976 but not 11/12/2010. I am using the following lines of codes but it does not work in some cases.

```
r'([^/](0?[1-9]|1[012])/(\d{4}))'
```

Comment: Is this enough `\b(?:\d{1,2}\/)?\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}\b` ?

Comment: No, that does not work. It returns 24/1990 (which is drawn from 5/24/1990).

Comment: `\b(?:\d{1,2}\/)?\d{1,2}\/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b` With the `\b` it forces it to be the start of the word.

Comment: That  uses month instead of day in a case like 11/1985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, a little bit explicit code, uses `re.sub` and `datetime.strptime` to parse/validate the input string:

```
import re
import datetime

s = '09/2010, 8/1976, 11/8/2010, 09/06/15, 12/1987, 13/2011, 09/13/2001'

r = re.compile(r'\b(\d{1,2})/(?:(\d{1,2})/)?(\d{2,4})\b')

def validate_date(g, parsed_values):
    if not g.group(2) is None:
        s = '{:02d}/{:02d}/{:04d}'.format(*map(int, g.groups()))
    else:
        s = '01/{:02d}/{:04d}'.format(int(g.group(1)), int(g.group(3)))

    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y')
        parsed_values.append(g.group())
        return
    except:
        pass

parsed_values = []
r.sub(lambda g: validate_date(g, parsed_values), s)

print(parsed_values)
```

Prints:

```
['09/2010', '8/1976', '11/8/2010', '09/06/15', '12/1987']
```

EDIT: Shortened the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

rgx = "(?:\d{1,2}\/)?\d{1,2}\/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?"
dates = "09/2010, 8/1976, 11/12/2010, 09/06/15 .."

result = re.findall(rgx, dates)
print(result)
# ['09/2010', '8/1976', '11/12/2010', '09/06/15']
```

Comment: You should have specified you were working with dataframes in your question. For your future questions try giving more context so we can help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

After working on this problem I came to this solution:

This works very well!

```
df['text'].str.extractall(r'(?P<Date>(?P<month>\d{1,2})/?(?P<day>\d{1,2})?/(?P<year>\d{2,4}))')
```